# iOS: Push notifications work only if the app run in foreground

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have 2 iPhones and I'm testing Apple push notifications.

They perfectly work when my app is running in foreground on both devices. But if I close it, by clicking on the Home button, I don't receive the notifications anymore.

The system doesn't show the notification popup. And I think this doesn't depend on my app code...

So far I've implemented

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

and it works great when the app is in foreground.
I've also implemented:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

but the launchOptions never contain the notification. However, this is correct, I guess, because the last method is invoked when I select a button of a notification alert that I never see...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call method `- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types` you should indicate appropriate type of argument. If you want to display alert when system receive push-notification for your device then you should pass `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert`.

Also you can combine types and pass it in that argument: `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually already passing it:  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];

Comment: Check push-settings in global settings for your app

Comment: everything is enabled (the app is also enabled). I've just checked. But the point is that I receive the notifications if the app is running in foreground, so they are allowed.

Comment: Do you pass text in json dictionary to APNS? ("alert"="text")

Comment: Not sure why UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert only was not working. After I've combined all arguments it worked out.

Comment: Hm, that's looks very strange. And what if you now remove all and set value `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert`? I'm now using alert and sound and all works fine.